# How can we receive the url into wso2 esb and give sucess response back to them

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-stratos, wso2-esb

I am going to receive the url(Ex:- www.google.com) into my WS02 ESB and send response back to them.
How can we receive the url's(Ex:- www.google.com) into wso2 esb and give sucess response back to them.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I assume you are creating a proxy service in WSO2 ESB. But what is not clear is the end to end scenario which you are trying to build. If you can provide details on it, I should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to response back to calling party with success HTTP response. Please set below property on your receiving path.

```
<property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
<property action="set" name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Jayalalk, it's working ,but if my url conains some data like www.w3schools.com , how can i receive this data into my service and send response to some other client.

Comment: There are many examples in following doc, please follow those, exmaple you can use script mediator to read incoming data and transform to new format before sending to other endpoint and etc.   http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+350%3A+Introduction+to+the+script+mediator+using+Javascript

Answer (score -1):

Does the ESB receive the URL as a property in the message context or are you referring to the URL where the request message is originated?

Comment: Thank you Anuradha, it's working ,but if my url contains some data like www.w3schools.com , how can i receive this data into my service and send response to some other client.